# @AttribueOverride(name="col1", column=@Column(nullable=true)) throwing cannot set field to null value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I have an embeddable type containing two fields mapped to columns. In that type both columns are set to `nullable = false`.

In another object which uses that embeddable type, I want to override the column name and set one of the columns to `nullable = true`.

`@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="col1", column=@Column(name="COL_1", nullable=true)),
        @AttributeOverride(name="col2", column=@Column(name="COL_2", nullable=false)) 
    })`

Seems fine, right?

When I run my code, I attempt to fetch a row where col1 is null, and I get this:

`org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter col1`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column is nullable, but the field in your entity is a primitive type (int, long, or boolean, presumably). There's no way for Hibernate to store null into a primitive type field. It should be Integer or Long or Boolean instead.

That's what the error message says: "Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type".